# Unable to get jquery response when form is submited using submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am sending state,city,zip code to ajax.php file. using jquery.
I am unable to get those values in response

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Jquery Ajax</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!------------------------Jquery-------POST DATA----------------------------------------->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {



        $('#id-submit').click(function() {


            var reg_state = $('#reg_state').val();
            var reg_city = $('#reg_city').val();
            var reg_zip = $('#reg_zip').val();

            var dataString = 'reg_state='+ reg_state;

            //alert(dataString);

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data)
                {
                //$("#state").html(data);
                 alert(data);
                } 
            });

        });

    });


    </script>
    <!------------------------Jquery-----------POST DATA END------------------------------------->

    <form id="registration_form" action="" method="post">

        <div id="state"></div>


         <div class="reg-id">
            <label>
                <input placeholder="State:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_state" id="reg_state" value="">
            </label>

        </div>

        <div class="reg-id">
            <label>
                <input placeholder="City:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_city" id="reg_city" value="">
            </label>
        </div>

         <div class="reg-id-last">
            <label>
                <input placeholder="Zip/Postal:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_zip" id="reg_zip" value="">
            </label>
        </div>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" tabindex="3" name="reg_btn" id="id-submit">
        </div>

    </form>



    </body>
    </html>
```

This is the ajax.php file , from where i need to send response, and make it visible in div id="state

```
<?php
if($_POST['reg_state'])
{
    echo $_POST['reg_state'];
}
else{

    echo 'nothing';
}
?>
```

Comment: Page is refreshing before you get the response from the server for the AJAX because you submitted the form. Either don't submit the form with a submit button, or bind to the submit event, and tell the form not to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When ever we use input['type']="submit" in form**

we have to use

```
$('#id-submit').click(function(e) { 

 e.preventDefault();
}
```

**Here is the full working code**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Jquery Ajax</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <!------------------------Jquery-------POST DATA----------------------------------------->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#id-submit').click(function(e) { 

                 e.preventDefault();

                var reg_state = $('#reg_state').val();
                var reg_city = $('#reg_city').val();
                var reg_zip = $('#reg_zip').val();

                var dataString = { reg_state: reg_state, reg_city: reg_city, reg_zip : reg_zip  }


                //alert(dataString);

                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax_city.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                    $("#state").html(data);
                    // alert('hi');
                    } 
                });

            });

        });


        </script>
        <!------------------------Jquery-----------POST DATA END------------------------------------->

        <form id="registration_form" action="" method="post">

            <div id="state"></div>


             <div class="reg-id">
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="State:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_state" id="reg_state" value="">
                </label>

            </div>

            <div class="reg-id">
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="City:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_city" id="reg_city" value="">
                </label>
            </div>

             <div class="reg-id-last">
                <label>
                    <input placeholder="Zip/Postal:" type="text" tabindex="3" name="user_zip" id="reg_zip" value="">
                </label>
            </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Response" tabindex="3" name="reg_btn" id="id-submit">
            </div>

        </form>



        </body>
        </html>
```

ajax_city.php

```
<?php
if($_POST['reg_state'])
{
    echo 'STATE: '.$_POST['reg_state'].'<br/>';
    echo 'CITY: '.$_POST['reg_city'].'<br/>';
    echo 'ZIP: '.$_POST['reg_zip'].'<br/>';

}
else{

    echo 'nothing to respond';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try create an object

```
var dataString = { reg_state: reg_state, reg_city: reg_city, reg_zip : reg_zip  }
```

Comment: i am not getting response from ajax.php file

Comment: I checked your script, you need update 18 line `$('#id-submit').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies in the `type=submit`. Replacing this with `type=button` gives you the result you want.

I'm unsure why this is, but I'm guessing it `type=submit` gives extra functionality to the `input`. The page seems to reload after hitting the submit button.

ps. don't forget you actually need to click the button in order for the function to trigger. Hitting enter after filling out the input fields will do nothing.

Comment: It's because it submits the form to the form action url. If none is specified, it submits to the page, causing a page refresh. Thus, the AJAX call does not complete before the page refreshes. He should just bind to the submit event instead of click event probably.

Comment: Why are you "guessing"?